# Adobe Illustrator: Run python file from Extendscript in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, system-calls, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

I am facing issue while running this script(time.jsx):

`var timeStr = system.callSystem("cmd.exe /c \"time /t\"");`

`alert("Current time is " + timeStr);` [Documentation of AE](https://blogs.adobe.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/48/files/2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf?file=2012/06/After-Effects-CS6-Scripting-Guide.pdf)

it works in *Adobe After Effects* but I want to use it specifically in illustrator. Basically, i want to run my **Python script from Extendscript(.jsx)**. But I couldn't find any solution to do so yet.

Your help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You could also get the current time directly in ExtendScript btw., should be much faster.

Comment: @mdomino Sorry, my wording sometime might be not understandable but this is an example i gave in question. Basically, i want to run Python script from .jsx file and getting errors if any occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found a way to execute Python or other scripts in Extendscripts(*.jsx), and that is it, there is named **File object** in [documentation](https://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/file-object.html) which has a function named **execute()**; which executes the scripts according to their [statement](https://estk.aenhancers.com/3%20-%20File%20System%20Access/file-object.html#execute). For example, you want to execute *hello world* in python through **.jsx** file, you need to make a **py file** including `print("hello world")`. After that, add these lines in the **script.jsx** script:

`var pyHello = new File("<path of py file>");`

`var bool = pyHello.execute();`

`alert(bool);`

If script executed, it would be **true**, otherwise, **false**,

Comment: Make sure your Python script's default application is Python Application.